# Mongodb - no suitable server

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I deployed a new cosmosDB with mongo and I have an appservice also in the azure. The appservice is a simple php application which connect to a collection (which is in cosmosDB). It works perfect except a connection problem. Cosmosdb throws sometimes this: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection closed calling ismaster on 'http://apidb.documents.azure.com:10250 '].

What could be the problem? Need to increase RU or need to change consistance settings?

PHP: 7.0.18, mongodb driver: 1.2.8, libmongoc version: 1.5.5 (as I read this problem should be fixed in 1.2.0 mongodb driver version)

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

If I remove repliceSet option from the connection string (azure said this option is recommanded), throws this error much less.

Comment: Could you please post more relevant information about your connectionstring? As far as I know, the azure mongodb connection string is using SSL and using 10255 port, not as the error shows.Besides, could you please post which PHP architecture you have used now,such as laravel.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Can you try setting serverSelectionTryOnce = false as per http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.construct.php and retrying your use case. As per your current setup, a single failure in isMaster request will cause the application to fail with the above mentioned error.

If you are still hitting the same error, please send the exact error message (and preferably the MongoLog http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongolog.php) to askcosmosmongoapi [at] microsoft [dot] com

Comment: It worked for me, thanks (serverSelectionTryOnce=false).